# How many ways can a six member student council be formed?

Tags: combinatorics

For this question, i have tried doing it in different permutations but the number doesn't make sense because it so big.

A VLC student council is being formed for the 2013-2014 school year. There are 20 applications received from interested students, with 11 of those students in grade 12. How many ways can a 6-member student council be formed if:

a) there are no restrictions?

b) there must be 3 grade 12's and 3 students from other grades?

c) there cannot be more than 2 grade 12's?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: (a) you have to choose 6 students out of 20 applicant.. This is just one line answer if you know what nCr means..

(b) Choose 3 out of 11 and 3 out of 9.

(c) for the last one break it into three cases 
Case 1: you have no  grade 12 student then you have to select 6 out of 9
Case 2: you have only one grade 12 student in which case choose 1 out of 11 and 5 out of 9
Case 3: you have only 2 grade 12 student in which case Choose 2 out of 12 and 4 out of 9.
Add the numbers you get from each case to get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no conditions then there are 20 choices for the first student, 19 for the second, down to 15 choices for the sixth.  By the "fundamental theorem of counting" the total choices are the product of those, 20(19)(18)(17)(16)(15) which can also be written as $\frac{20!}{14!}$.  Since the particular order is not relevant, we need to divide by the number of different orders of those same 6 people, 6!.  That gives $\frac{20!}{14!6!}$ which you might recognize as a "binomial coefficient", often written $\begin{pmatrix}14 \\ 6\end{pmatrix}$ or $_{14}C_6$.

Comment: It's 20C6..I think you have mistaken that part..